# If exists, keep on looking, check again and repeat. Do while loop in PHP

Tags: php

```
$number = 1;
do{
    $list_name = "Unnamed list ".$number;

    $list_name_exists = DB::select('name')->from('shoppinglists')->where('name', '=', $list_name)->execute()->count(); // returns 1 or 0

    $number++;
}while($list_name_exists == 0);
echo $list_name; // I want it here to output a name, that doesnt exists in the db.
```

What i tried to do above was to set $list_name, to a name that does not exists already in the db.

But it does not seem to work, and page loads quite some time.

How can i do this right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the list number as a separate column, so that you can do

```
SELECT MAX(list_number) + 1 AS new_number FROM lists
```

and find out immediately which number you should use. There is no sense in making 10000 queries just so that you can find that the next available number is 10001.

That said, it is still possible that by the time you get to using `new_number` it will no longer be valid (because perhaps another request from another user has taken up the same number). This will depend on the transaction isolation level of the database and of course if you are using transactions or not.

If you do not want to go deep into transaction territory, you can simply make sure there is a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` key on the `list_number` column. You will also have to keep the while-not-successful loop. The difference is that now the loop will be executed a few times at most, not possibly tens of thousands of times.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is taking a long time to finish because you're executing a database query on each pass of your `do/while` loop. I'd just select the highest ID from your database and use that (plus one) as your new list name.

Pseudo code:

```
<?php

// initiate database connection
$sql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_name";
$res = $db->query($sql);
$row = $res->fetch();

$new_list_name = (intval($row) + 1);
```

The only download of this is, you may find a race condition where two people visit your site and get assigned the same ID before saving their list name back to the database. In this case, you could simply just use a unique ID instead.

```
<?php

// make a unique ID to use as list name
$new_list_name = uniqid();
```

Simples.